# Pass a pointer in the same line as executing a method in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

Say you have the following class

```cpp
template <class T>
class BinarySearchTree {
private:
    Node<T> root;
public:
    Node<T>* deleteNode(T value) {
        Node<T>* rootPointer = &this->root;
        return deleteNode(rootPointer, value);
    }
    /*
    Delete specific value in the root provided
    */
    Node<T>* deleteNode(Node<T> *& root, T value) {
       //here be magic
    }
}
```

in the overload without a pointer to `Node<T>` :  `deleteNode` method you see I get the pointer to `this->root` and after that pass it to the actual workhorse, the other `deleteNode` method.

Is there a way to do this... a bit more elegantly? My thought process was that I could do:

```cpp
return deleteNode(&this->root, value);
```

but the compiler will give me

```
'Node<T> *Bst<T>::deleteNode(Node<T> *&,T)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Node<T> *' to 'Node<T> *&'
```

My main question is, what is going wrong with my thought process? Am I doing this correctly/the C++ way?

Comment: Why do you pass pointer by reference?

Comment: Which would imply I wanted to edit the pointer, and not the value given. Fair point.  Let me check my code.. I just thought you'd want to pass everything by reference, so not to copy things all over the place. But a pointer isn't too bad to copy ofcourse..

Comment: @VTT thanks for your question, it helped my find the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @VTT

To make sure I actually learn something:

What I did was pass a pointer by reference `&` indicated that we are passing by reference and '*' indicates that the variable is a pointer.

If i wanted the onlineliner I should've just used `(Node<T>* root)` instead of `(Node<T>*& root)`. Passing a pointer by reference has its uses, but this is not it.

Comment: Note that you could use a reference like you wanted, but only if the type was `Node<T>* const &` (i.e. *reference to a const pointer to Node<T>*).  You cannot bind a reference to temporary, because temporary will not live long enough for reference to be useful. Const references (references to const objects) are special, because they will prolong lifetime of temporary object as long as the reference exists.

Comment: alright @Yksisarvinen you wrinkled my brain, I will have to investigate the use of const pointer to Node<T>, Because "const" screams: dont change me. To me, but apparently that's not how it works....

Is there a difference between `Node<T>* const` and `Node<T> *& ` ?

Comment: Yes, it does mean "don't change me". But when calling function like this: `deleteNode(&this->root, value);`, this part: `&this->root` is a temporary value. I assumed you don't care that the pointer will not change. If you want to change the pointer inside `deleteNode`, then you will need to copy it (the pointer) like in your answer.